# Interactive Brokers Symbol list

Tags: interactive-brokers

I want to use the IB Api, but cannot figure our how the request a complete symbol list and information.

In the Documentation i found: reqScannerParameters() - but it is not clear how to get a list for example of nasdaq stocks ?

Is there a better way ?

Comment: ? im using ib not tradeking

Comment: Yes, I know that, I was trying to save you a lot of grief, in response to your "is there a better way" question.

Comment: :P ib is mutch cheaper then tradeking ...

Comment: After having IB trade against me, I'm not so sure about that..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76280/discussion-between-brian-topping-and-roby).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I am aware IB does not offer a symbol list. But the good news is it is easy and free to get elsewhere. Eoddata.com is a good source of it and you can download them, or automate it rather easily.

Go here and just click the download link at the top right of the table: [EodData Symbol List](http://www.eoddata.com/symbols.aspx)

Not sure what language your using for the IB API but I have simple tutorial in C# that covers reading the tickers for stocks and options on my website: [Get Real-Time Stock Data from the Interactive Brokers API](http://www.jarloo.com/get-real-time-stock-data-using-the-interactive-brokers-api/)

Comment: Great job, this really helps me!

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly easy to implement a piece of code scraping all stocks symbol from IB's website.

NYSE stocks are available from [IB website](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/?f=%2Fen%2Ftrading%2Fexchanges.php%3Fshowcategories%3DSTK%26amp%3Bsortproducts%3DIS%26amp%3Bshowproducts%3DAll%26amp%3Bsearch.x%3D68%26amp%3Bsearch.y%3D18%26amp%3Bexch%3Dnyse%26amp%3Bib_entity%3Dllc%26amp%3Bf%3D2222#show)

Just replace 'nyse' with another exchange's name like nasdaq or amex.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to their products listing you can drill down to find lists of the entire universe of products (in case the link expires, I just googled "IB Product Listings")

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=1563

For example, I went to their NYSE product and scrolled through a few pages to find everything I needed. Here's an example of what I found

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=2222&exch=amex&showcategories=STK&p=&cc=&limit=100&page=3